# MongoDB: changing document structure query

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

We have made a change in our data model and we would like to apply it to all documents in one of our collections:

```
{
  "id":60,
  "measurement":{
    "steps":1274.0
  },
  "date":"2012-05-15T00:00:00Z"
}
```

to:

```
{  
  "id":60,
  "measurement":{
      "distance":{
          "steps":1274.0}
      },
  "date":"2012-05-15T00:00:00Z"
}
```

Essentially, we want to further nest the field `steps`, placing it under the `distance` field.

As for `measurement.step`, we would like to convert `measurement.miles` to `measurement.distance.miles` and `measurement.minutes` to `measurement.time.minutes`.

Any thoughts and/or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're asking how to script the schema change, which wasn't quite clear in the question: I would do something like this, unless you have more cases for the document structure, or mixed cases:

```
// find all the measurement documents with steps
db.coll.find({"measurement.steps":{$exists:true}}).forEach(function(doc) {      
  // create a new distance subdoc with the steps
  doc.measurement.distance = {steps:doc.measurement.steps};
  // delete the old steps subdoc
  delete doc.measurement.steps;
  // save the document
  db.coll.save(doc);
});
// find all the measurement documents with miles
db.coll.find({"measurement.miles":{$exists:true}}).forEach(function(doc) {
  // create a new distance subdoc with the miles
  doc.measurement.distance = {miles:doc.measurement.miles};
  delete doc.measurement.miles;
  db.coll.save(doc);
});
// find all the measurement documents with minutes
db.coll.find({"measurement.minutes":{$exists:true}}).forEach(function(doc) {
  // create a new time subdoc with the minutes
  doc.measurement.time = {minutes:doc.measurement.minutes};
  delete doc.measurement.minutes;
  db.coll.save(doc);
});
```

You could pretty easily do the equivalent in the language/driver of your choice to ensure types, but it is probably faster to do in the shell. Hope it helps.

Comment: can it be scaled for data with around 5million documents?